# Paypal _cart not showing tax and shipping in sandbox

Tags: paypal

I've got a paypal form to request a payment that I'm testing in www.sandbox.paypal.com.

It works as I expect, except for tax and shipping costs, that are ignored and not shown in paypal cart and not computed in cart total amount.

In this case I only have one product, but buyers can add more products to their carts.

I can't understand where I'm going wrong.

```
<form method="post" name="paypal_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">

   <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_cart'>
   <input type='hidden' name='business' value='myEmail'>
   <input type='hidden' name='charset' value='utf-8'>
   <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='EUR'>
   <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://mysite/shop/ipn_url.php'>
   <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='xxxaasxdfd'>
   <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://mysite/shop/confirm_url.php'>
   <input type='hidden' name='lc' value='IT'>
   <input type='hidden' name='email' value='buyer@mysite'>
   <input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='Test name'>
   <input type='hidden' name='last_name' value='Test surname'>
   <input type='hidden' name='zip' value='00000'>
   <input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='1'>
   <input type='hidden' name='cbt' value='Return to mysite'>
   <input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
   <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://mysite/shop/cancel_url.php'>
   <input type='hidden' name='upload' value='1'><input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='129.00'>
   <input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='23-PROD11'>
   <input type='hidden' name='item_number_1' value='120'>
   <input type='hidden' name='tax' value='39.37'>
   <input type='hidden' name='shipping' id='shipping' value='67.87'>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the VAT and the shipping cost are visible and computed if I pass them for every single item in my cart.

```
<input type='hidden' name='shipping_1' id='shipping' value='67.87'>
<input type='hidden' name='tax_1' value='39.37'>
```

I've charged them on the first item as `shipping_1` and `tax_1` in the cart for all my items, in this way I'm sure that it will work for cart with one or more items.